Paradox $1<1$ using complex exponentiation

\begin{align*}
1&>e^{-4\pi^2} \\
&= e^{(2\pi i)(2\pi i)} \\
&= (e^{2\pi i})^{2\pi i} \tag{$\ast$} \\
&= 1^{2\pi i}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

The problem with this fake proof is that if we considered the principal branch of logarithm, $\operatorname{Log}$:
$$\large(e^{2\pi i})^{2\pi i}=e^{\operatorname{Log}(e^{2\pi i})2 \pi i}= e^{(\log(1)+i \cdot 0)2 \pi i}=1$$
So, the second equality would be false and the fake proof uses the fact that the logarithm is multi-valued for the exponentiation. Is this idea correct?

look at here and here

$\operatorname{Log}(\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}})=\log(|\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}}|)+\mathrm{i}\arg(\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}})=0+\mathrm{i},2\pi=2\pi \mathrm{i}$.

@Gary, using the principal branch of logarithm, shouldn't the principal argument be $0$ ($-\pi<0<\pi$)?

I was using the multivalued logarithm. What you say in your question is correct.
